# How to run a server-side function from client-side javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

debug.html

```
<head>
<script src="debugBoot.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<button onclick="alert(dss.getParameters())">Get Params</button>

</body>
```

debugBoot.js

```
var dss = {};

var INVALID_PARAM = -1;

function init() {

dss.getParameters = function(){
    var rest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    rest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/MW-war/rest/mw/enumerateParams", false);
    var data=rest.responseText;
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);   //line 11
    console.log(jsonResponse["Data"]);
    rest.send(jsonResponse);
    return JSON.parse(data);
};
```

}

MWRest (interface)

```
@GET
@Path("/enumerateParams")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String[][] enumerateParams();
```

myJavaClass

```
    @Override
    public String[][] enumerateParams() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return new String[][] { { "" + PATIENT_ID, "PATIENT_ID" }, { "" + AGE, "AGE" },
            { "" + BLOOD_PRESSURE, "BLOOD_PRESSURE" }, { "" + GENDER, "GENDER" },
            { "" + SMOKING_HABITS, "SMOKING_HABITS" }, { "" + DIET_FRUITS_VEGGIES, "DIET_FRUITS_VEGGIES" },
            { "" + CHOLESTEROL, "CHOLESTEROL" }, { "" + ALCOHOL, "ALCOHOL" }, { "" + ACTIVITY, "ACTIVITY" },
            { "" + QUIT_SMOKING, "QUIT_SMOKING" }, { "" + DIET_CEREAL_FIBRE, "DIET_CEREAL_FIBRE" } };
}
```

I need do be able to do the stuff from debugBoot.js 
Once I press the button (chrom f12 in debug mode), I jump into the debugBoot.js and go through the lines with f10 and when i come to the line

```
var data=rest.responseText;
```

data is empty...
and when I go on to the line

```
 var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
```

there is an error:

```
VM5402:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.dss.getParameters (debugBoot.js:11)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (debug.html?scriptId=2:18)
```

I forgot to say:
Once i go on this link:

http://localhost:8080/MW-war/rest/mw/enumerateParams

I get this as an output:

```
[["0","PATIENT_ID"],["1","AGE"],["2","BLOOD_PRESSURE"],["3","GENDER"],["4","SMOKING_HABITS"],["5","DIET_FRUITS_VEGGIES"],["6","CHOLESTEROL"],["7","ALCOHOL"],["8","ACTIVITY"],["9","QUIT_SMOKING"],["10","DIET_CEREAL_FIBRE"]]
```

I googled a lot, and found some not so similar questions, but nothing too similar to my problem...any suggestions?

Comment: You aren't actually sending the request, are you? Also the response would be asynchronous, not instantaneous. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for examples

Comment: Ok, you are sending the request, but *after* you try to read the response.

Comment: how am i not sending the request? with rest.open() and the 3rd param in it should set the asynchronous to synchronus, shouldnt it?

Comment: the 3rd parameter should be a boolean, not a string. Also the request isn't sent until you call `send`

Comment: kk, thx, i changed it, but its still the same error

Comment: You still need to call `rest.send(null)` before the request is actually sent. `open` does not send a request. See [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) for examples of synchronous usage

Comment: thx man, I ll look it through

Answer (score 0):

```
dss.getParameters = function(){
    var rest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    rest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/MW-war/rest/mw/enumerateParams", false);
    rest.send(null);
    if (rest.status === 200) {
      console.log(rest.responseText);
    }
    return JSON.parse(rest.responseText);
};
```

this works...thx a lot...now i have a similar task with a POST method :)

once i press the button, i get the wished result

hope this helps someone in the future ;)